# Login through portal and trying to load HTML

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have a C# program that logs into a portal, and then needs to test if an element with a specific ID exists on the page or not.  In order to test for this, I grab the HTML from the page and search for an element with a matching ID in the HTML.

However, whenever I try to access the HTML with this script, it always returns the HTML of the portal login page, and not the page after one logs in through the portal.  I can confirm 100% that the program is logging into the portal, however for some reason it is still returning the wrong HTML.

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string html = client.DownloadString(this.currentStepUrl);
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var foo = (from bar in doc.DocumentNode.DescendantNodes()
          where bar.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == expected
          select bar).FirstOrDefault();
if (foo != null)
{
    currentTestCaseResults[0]++;
}
else
{
    currentTestCaseResults[1]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy fix I guess:

Replaced everything but the if clause with

```
HtmlElement expectedElement webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById(expected);
```